# React native app always crash in IOS using EAS build

Tags: react-native, crash, eas

I'm building very simple ReactNative app bare-wrokflow using expo modules and I'm trying to build internal test , but the app crash immediately.

I literally rendering one screen and works with no error in IOS simulator.

The build command is ( eas build --profile preview --platform ios )
I followed all the configuration in the docs.

Note : I'm not using navigation at all.
Note : I had same problem with another app that uses navigation.

expo version : 45
expo-cli : 5.6.0
react native version :68.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the issue.
I did two things and it works for me.

First thing : 
 I installed some of the packages via npm , so I reinstall them using expo.

Second (it's most likely the issue) : 
  My app was consuming an API I built with node.js for auth purposes , and that API was using (nodeMailer) using gmail , and google changed some of security settings , so my nodemailer doesn't send email confirmations , so I fix that + I uninstalled cors library for security reasons .

after that everything works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

What iOS version? There are known issues with apps crashing and not being openable in iOS 15. In iOS 15, apple removed certain directories which caused many apps to crash on certain iPhones (specifically phones w/o face ID in Geometry Dash's case). I can't find more details on it since the google search is bloated with other results when I search it up.

Comment: Thanks for reply .iPhone Xs , Software Version 15.5